# Getting Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ServerError: status code 400

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rubygems, watir

The following gems are up to date: rubygems, watir, selenium-webdriver.

I do the following at command line:

```
$irb
>require 'watir' (returns true)
>BROWSER=Watir::Browser.new :firefox (returns #<Watir::Browser:0x2b7c618 url="about:blank" title="">)
>BROWSER.goto('google.ca') (returns "http://google.ca")
>BROWSER.text_field(:name => 'q').exists? (returns true)
>BROWSER.text_field(:name => 'q').set('test')
```

At that point I get the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ServerError: status code 400
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:74:in 'assert_ok'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in 'initialize'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in 'new'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in 'create_response'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:106:in 'request'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:61:in 'call'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:170:in 'execute'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:537:in 'execute'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:367:in 'send_keys_to_element'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:156:in 'send_keys'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-6.8.4/lib/watir/user_editable.rb:13:in 'block in set'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-6.8.4/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:657:in 'element_call'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-6.8.4/lib/watir/user_editable.rb:11:in `set'
    from (irb):19
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/irb:11:in '<main>'
```

I also tried .send_keys('test') and got the same error. If it can find the element, I don't understand why I can't enter text into the element.

Comment: What version of geckodriver?

Comment: Hi, I am using geckodriver 0.14.0

Comment: Update your geckodriver. :-)

Comment: Thanks @titusfortner, I updated to geckodriver 0.19.0 and it seems to be working now. And here I thought I had everything updated *sigh*

Comment: I recommend people whose browsers auto update use the webdrivers gem to keep their drivers auto updated.